# Oracle SQL - 'Group By' defined at run time

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Simply put, my question is if something like the following is possible.  The way I am doing it does NOT work, but maybe there is some alternate solution.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Semester,
  Class,
  Sum(Hours) as Hours
FROM Student
GROUP BY
  Case '&GroupType'
    When 'Semester_Class' Then Semester || Class
    When 'Semester'       Then Semester
    When 'Class_Semester' Then Class || Semester
    When 'Class'          Then Class
    When 'Summary'        Then ID
    End
```

This, of course, doesn't work (and shouldn't) but that would be the concept.  (As a note, this DOES work for `Order By` clauses). If the user choses a `&GroupType` of `Semester_Class`, the report would summarize how many hours total one class type (say English 101) had per semester.

I think I'm just dreaming and that without PL/SQL (or maybe even with) this just isn't possible.  However, I thought someone might have a clever solution.

If further clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: How is the user making this selection?

Comment: @Dan I'm using a reporting software that allows the user to use variables to input data.  Where it says `'&GroupType'` should really say `:GroupType` as there is no way (I am aware of) to be able to inject SQL using this reporting tool.  Whereas, in at least PL/SQL, you can inject SQL using the `&` prefix.

Edit: But to answer your question, the `'&GroupType'` is populated by a dropdown with options corresponding to the 'When' statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will not work because the columns in the `select` don't match the columns in the `group by`.

You could do something like this (assuming you are using PL/SQL):

```
select (Case :GroupType
          When 'Semester_Class' Then Semester || Class
          When 'Semester'       Then Semester
          When 'Class_Semester' Then Class || Semester
          When 'Class'          Then Class
          When 'Summary'        Then ID
        End
       ) as which, count(*)
from Student
group by (Case :GroupType
            When 'Semester_Class' Then Semester || Class
            When 'Semester'       Then Semester
            When 'Class_Semester' Then Class || Semester
            When 'Class'          Then Class
            When 'Summary'        Then ID
          End
         );
```